# Auto Repeat Isset Post Until Requirements met

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php code that updates mysql tables with results of a fight.
When you press the button fight you excetude the below:

```
if(isset($_POST['attack_creature'])){

    if($monnewhealth > "0"){  //if Monster exists
            if($charhealth > "0"){ //if Character is alive go to fight
                $fightcreature = "UPDATE user_character SET current_action_points = current_action_points-$fight_action_points WHERE ID = $currentUser AND current_action_points>$fight_action_points"; 
                $stmt = $con->prepare($fightcreature);
                $stmt->execute();
                if($totalinflicteddamagetocreature > "0") {
                $monnewhealth = $monnewhealth - $totalinflicteddamagetocreature;
                if($monnewhealth < "0") {
                $monnewhealth = 0;
                }   
                $updatenmonewhealth = "UPDATE user_character SET fight_creature_new_health = $monnewhealth WHERE ID = $currentUser";
                $stmt = $con->prepare($updatenmonewhealth);
                $stmt->execute();
                }
                if($monnewhealth <= "0"){
                $lastFight = $now_time;
                $updatecharlastfightkills = "UPDATE user_character SET character_last_fight = $now_time, character_kills = $charkills+1, character_gold = $chargold+$mongoldreward, character_current_xp = $charexp+$monxpreward, current_xp_reward = $monxpreward, current_gold_reward = $mongoldreward  WHERE ID = $currentUser";
                $stmt = $con->prepare($updatecharlastfightkills);
                $stmt->execute();
                $insertbattlelog1 = "INSERT INTO battle_log (ID, battle_log_date, battle_log_result, battle_log_enemy_name, battle_log_enemy_lvl, battle_log_gold, battle_log_xp, battle_log_event) VALUES ('$currentUser', '$now_time', '1', '$monname', '$monlvl', '$charlastgoldreward', '$charlastxpreward', 'You have Destroyed  Level $monlvl $monname and earned $monxpreward XP and $mongoldreward')";
                mysqli_query($con, $insertbattlelog1);
                }
                    if($monnewhealth > "0"){    //if Monster still alive

                        if($totalinflicteddamagetocharacter > "0") {
                        $charhealth = $charhealth - $totalinflicteddamagetocharacter;
                        if($charhealth < "0") {
                        $charhealth = 0;
                        }   
                        $updatecharnewhealth = "UPDATE user_character SET current_health = $charhealth WHERE ID = $currentUser";
                        $stmt = $con->prepare($updatecharnewhealth);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        }
                        if($charhealth <= "0"){
                        $updatecharlastfightdeaths = "UPDATE user_character SET character_last_fight = $now_time, character_deaths = $chardeaths+1 WHERE ID = $currentUser";
                        $stmt = $con->prepare($updatecharlastfightdeaths);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $insertbattlelog2 = "INSERT INTO battle_log (ID, battle_log_date, battle_log_result, battle_log_enemy_name, battle_log_enemy_lvl, battle_log_event) VALUES ('$currentUser', '$now_time', '2', '$monname', '$monlvl', '$charlastgoldreward', '$charlastxpreward', 'You have been killed by Level $monlvl $monname')";
                        mysqli_query($con, $insertbattlelog2);
                        }
                    }   
            }
}
 header('Location: hunt.php');
}
```

I don't know how to repeat this process until monhealth or charhealth reach 0 Zero.
Also I want to log how many rounds took to reach 0 Zero and log every round totaldamages.

Many thank you in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function and call it recursively with a condition.

```
function doIt() {
  if($condition > 0) {
    doIt();
  }
}
doIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `if` just use `while` so if the $monnewhealth is still greater than 0 i will rerun the code block. and also add new variable $rounds thats increase on each round. something like the code below.

```
$rounds = 0;
 while ($monnewhealth > "0") { // if($monnewhealth > "0"){
    $rounds++; // this will cound your rounds
    while ($charhealth > "0") { // if($charhealth > "0"){
        // your huge code block here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A while loop would work in this case:

```php
$roundCount = 0;
while($monnewhealth > 0 && $charhealth > 0) {

    ++$roundCount;

    // Your current code
}
```

Comment: Seems to work spectacullar. Now how to echo each counts results ?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want to echo

Comment: At first I want to echo how many rounds it took to complete. A simple echo $roundCount; doesn’t give me the number I don’t know why.